# use split() to split string like "004*034556"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, split

In my project I used the code to split string like "004*034556" , code is like below :

```
String string = "004*034556";
String[] parts = string.split("*");
```

but it got some error and force closed !!
finally I found that if use "#" or another things its gonna work .

```
String string = "004#034556";
String[] parts = string.split("#");
```

how can I explain this ?!

Comment: See the documentation for `split()`.  (and read the error)

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to treat the `*` like the String `*` and not the Regex `*` (that have a [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)):

```
String[] parts = string.split(Pattern.quote("*"));
```

See [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public String[] split(String regex)
                             ↑
```

Answer (score 2):

Your forgetting something very trivial.

```
String string = "004*034556";
String[] parts = string.split("\\*");
```

I recommend you check out [Escape Characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 1):

Refer [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
 String[] split(String regex) 

 Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
```

And the symbol "*" has a different meaning when we talk about [Regex in Java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Thus you would have to use an escape character

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\*");
```